# Compatibility issues In Windows Update

Tags: windows, windows-update

Has anyone experienced any compatibility issues with the latest Windows update and Adobe Creative Cloud software?

I've noticed some glitches and wondering if it's just me or if others are experiencing similar issues

Comment: Probably best to contact Microsoft support.

Comment: Microsoft doesn’t offer customer service…Adobe might…

Comment: Adobe thoroughly botched their most recent Reader Update and that may have spread into other Adobe Apps. I was able to find the complete new MSI on the Adobe site and fix my issues. I do not know about Creative Cloud.